# Looking for a cheaper way to update controls than Update()

Tags: c#, controls

In a large loop I change several values and need them to be `updatet`. I `dont want` to use a `BackGroundWorker`.

Is there a cheaper way to make the updates, something like to tell the application to `paint all pending changes`?

```
void ExampleFunc()
{
    // The original function is more complex
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        MyControl1.Text = NewText1(i);
        MyControl2.Text = OtherNewText(i);

        MyControl1.Update();
        MyControl1.Update();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Why I do need to do it this way:
I usually use BackGroundWorker for situations like that, but in this case on some PCs I get problems with the invokes. So I can't use use it in this case

Comment: Why are you updating 10000 times anyway? It's not like the user is going to be able to see that happening. Update *is* a way to run all pending changes and you make one change on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Also, note that the standard solution is to perform work on a separate thread so that the UI can paint itself whenever that is necessary.

Comment: 10000 is just an example. Its a long running loop and the user needs the feedback whats happening. Yes, I usually use BackGroundWorker for situations like that, but in this case on some PCs I get problems with the invokes. So I can't use use it in this case.

Comment: Sounds like you should rather fix the bug that you have with backgroundworker. Anyway, did you understand my remarks in the first comment? You are generating tons of changes which is why it's taking a long time. Generate less changes.

Comment: @usr yes I understood your remarks and I tried to find the bug. But its happening only on the customer machines and nobody will pay us to fix it using a second thread. And no, I cant make less changes.

Comment: Then you're out of luck. Repainting is expensive. What about painting every 10th iteration or only if 100ms have passed?

Comment: Yes, good idea! That should work. I must write every iteration but I can wait some milliseconds. Thx. Like to write it as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you cannot use a separate thread and that you must repaint often enough to give the user feedback.

Repainting is expensive. Paint every 10th iteration or every 100ms to reduce the overhead.